# Possible to track Outlook tasks on Windows Mobile

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange, windows-mobile, scheduled-tasks

**I'm trying to view/add/edit MS Outlook 2007 tasks on a work PDA running Windows Mobile 6 Professional (sync'ed with MS Exchange 2007).**

1) is this possible? From a quick Google search I can't find anything... However I may be missing something obvious.

2) if not, any ideas about work-arounds?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly are you asking? Do you want to be able to sync tasks on your WinMo device with Exchange?

Comment: Sorry - I'm trying to view & manage tasks on my WinMo device - I can't work out how to do that. 

The tasks are currently on Outlook 2007 (which is linked to MS Exchange). Emails and calender items are sync'ing fine, I just can't work out where tasks are.

Answer (score 1):

Have discovered that this is just a simple case of not finding the setting to turn on sync'ing.

On the device itself, it's Start > Programmes > ActiveSync > Menu > Options > then check the 'Tasks' checkbox...